# Where ActionListener's actionPerformed() is called in a code

Tags: java, swing, anonymous-class

Here is a code which handles button click:

```
   JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // handle the button click
        }
    });
```

I know that `actionPerfomed` is called when a user clicks a button. But where to find the call in the Java source code library? Where does all the magic happen?

Comment: What magic exactly? Swing has an event based paradigm. You override the listener method in question and your code gets invoked.

Comment: `javax.swing.AbstractButton@1952`, this is where `fireActionPerformed` is defined.  The button attaches it's own `ActionListener` to the `ButtonModel`

Comment: If you dig deep enough, you'll come across `BasicButtonIU`, this base UI delegate class.  It attaches a number of listeners and coordinates the operations against the `ButtonModel` itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer, then how does it happen, that when user clicks a button, fireActionPerformed is called?

Comment: Dig into the code, when the mouse listener is triggers, it triggers the button model which triggers a action lister which truggers the button itself to trigger your action listener - if you’re running on windows, you’ll probably have a src.jar